# Prevent SQL statement from executing on JSP page load

Tags: java, sql, jsp

How can I have a SQL statement that updates data when a button is clicked, not execute when the page loads?

I have a very simple table that has a player name, a player score, and player id attributes and only one row. When I am on this page, I want the button to execute the update query to increase player score, but it's happening every time the page loads.

Is there a boolean or something I can set to prevent it from adding 1 to the player score on every load?

Please don't ask why I'm using a JSP in this context. It's bad to do, I know, but these are my requirements.

Here is my code:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html" %>
<%@ page import="java.text.DecimalFormat" %>
<%@ page import="java.sql.Connection" %>
<%@ page import="java.sql.DriverManager" %>
<%@ page import="java.sql.ResultSet" %>
<%@ page import="java.sql.Statement" %>
<%@ page import="java.lang*" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Player scores</title>
    <script>
      function reloadPage() {
        location.reload();
      }
    </script>
  </head>    
  <body>
  <%!
    String name = "";
    Integer score = 0;
    Integer pID = 0;
  %>
  <form name="form1" method="POST" onsubmit="return false">
    <p align="center">
      <input type="BUTTON" value="+" onclick="reloadPage();"/>
    </p>

    <%
      try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test", "root", "admin");
        Statement stmnt = conn.createStatement();
        stmnt.executeUpdate("update players set playerScore=playerScore+1 where playerID=1");
      } catch (Exception e) {
      }
    %>
  </form>

  <%
  try {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test", "root", "admin");
    Statement stmnt = conn.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = stmnt.executeQuery("select playerID, playerName, playerScore from players where playerID=1");
    if (rs.next()) {
       name = rs.getString("playerName");
       score = rs.getInt("playerScore");
       pID = rs.getInt("playerID");
    } else {
      name = "-";
      score = 0;
      pID = 404;
    }
  } catch(Exception e) {
  }
  %>
  <table align="center">
    <tr>
      <th>Player name:</th>
      <td id="pID"><%=name%></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Player score:</th>
      <td id="pN"><%=score%></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Player id:</th>
      <td id="pi"><%=pID%></td>
    </tr>
    <p class="center">
      <a href="Page2.jsp">Go back</a>
    </p>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

**The update code always gets executed because you have your code written that way.**

This code:

```
<form name="form1" method="POST" onsubmit="return false">
    <p align="center">
      <input type="BUTTON" value="+" onclick="reloadPage();"/>
    </p>
```

that calls:

```
<script>
  function reloadPage() {
    location.reload();
  }
</script>
```

is just a refresh with no extra parameters. You always perform a GET.

**You need to tell the JSP to do something different when you click the `+` button.** You might try something like this (please have a look at [this tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_form_processing.htm) first):

```
<form name="form1" method="POST" action="yourJSPWhateverIsCalled.jsp">
  <p align="center">
    <input type="submit" value="+" name="increaseScore" />
  </p>
```

Then guard your update code with an `if`:

```
<%
  if (request.getParameter("increaseScore") != null) {
    try {
      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
      Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test", "root", "admin");
      Statement stmnt = conn.createStatement();
      stmnt.executeUpdate("update players set playerScore=playerScore+1 where playerID=1");
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
  }
%>
```

`Class.forName` is needed only once and you could reuse the connection to create the statements but that's another story. Also, **a JSP isn't the place to postprocess a form submit (use a plain vanilla servlet)**.

**One other problem with your code is that the JSP is thread UNsafe** because of this definition:

```
<%!
    String name = "";
    Integer score = 0;
    Integer pID = 0;
%>
```

If you use `<%!` the code is placed at servlet class level when your JSP gets translated to a servlet and not inside the `_jspService` method where it belongs. You are basically adding state to your JSP which is thread unsafe because the servlet container can reuse the same servlet instance to handle multiple requests.

**Finally, I would strongly suggest you to read a JSP tutorial before continuing.** An official tutorial is [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnagx.html).